# Kubernetes Cross Namespace Ingress Network

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, kubernetes-ingress

I have a simple ingress network, I want to access services at different namespaces, from this ingress network.

How I can do this? 
My ingress network yaml file:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
spec:
  rules:
 - host: api.myhost.com
 http:
 paths:
  - backend:
      serviceName: bookapi-2
      servicePort: 8080
    path: /booking-service/
```

I've set the ExternalNames service type to the yaml file:

```
 apiVersion: v1
 kind: Service
 metadata:
   name: bookapi-2
   namespace: booking-namespace
 spec:
   type: ExternalName
   externalName: bookapi-2
   ports:
     - name: app
     protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
   selector:
      app: bookapi-2
      tier: backend-2
```

Comment: There's a good demo in https://github.com/ProProgrammer/cross-namespace-nginx-ingress-kubernetes which is linked from https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/17088 but I don't know if you've happy to use nginx ingress

Answer (score 41):

> An ExternalName service is a special case of service that does not
>   have selectors and uses DNS names instead.

You can find out more about ExternalName service from the official [Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname):

When  you want to access a service from a different namespace, your yaml could, for [example](https://akomljen.com/kubernetes-tips-part-1/), look like this:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: test-service-1
  namespace: namespace-a
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: test-service-2.namespace-b.svc.cluster.local
  ports:
  - port: 80
```

As to your Ingress yaml file, please recheck it and make sure it is compliant with the official examples, for [example](https://medium.com/@cashisclay/kubernetes-ingress-82aa960f658e) this one as it contains some inconsistency:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1  
kind: Ingress  
metadata:  
  name: my-ingress  
spec:  
  rules:  
  - host: www.mysite.com  
    http:  
      paths:  
      - backend:  
          serviceName: website  
          servicePort: 80  
  - host: forums.mysite.com  
    http:  
      paths:  
      - path:  
        backend:  
          serviceName: forums  
          servicePort: 80
```

Please also recheck ExternalName yaml as it has TargetPorts and selectors which are not used in this type of [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) and make sure that:

> ExternalName Services are available only with `kube-dns` version 1.7
>   and later.

In case you will not succeed, please share the kind of problem you have meet.

Comment: Just in case it helps a future reader: when I run `kubectl describe ingress` I see an error saying that no endpoints are found for the ExternalName Service. Things work just fine though. (On microk8s, for `externalName: kubernetes-dashboard.kube-system.svc.cluster.local`.)

Comment: @Arjan I get error `service "default/service-name" is type "ExternalName", expected "NodePort" or "LoadBalancer"` and it doesn't work. Did you do something different else?

Comment: @aurelis Didn't work. get this error: `Translation failed: invalid ingress spec: service "hello/nginx-external" is type "ExternalName", expected "NodePort" or "LoadBalancer"`

Comment: First, did you really mean to point the Ingress to the "external" service `test-service-1` which is pointing to another service in a different namespace? I am not sure if you really meant this as your Ingress is pointing to completely different service names...
Anyway, on GKE, this setup is not working as it requires healthcheck on the backend service and it always fails for the external service (it's configured properly and manually tested).

Answer (score 6):

1. create namespace service-ns
2. create a service of type ClusterIP ( which is default ) named nginx-service listening on port 80 in namespace service-ns
3. create nginx deployment in service-ns
4. create namespace ingress-ns
5. create a service in ingress-ns of type ExternalName and pointing to FQDN of nginx-service pointing it as nginx-internal.service-ns.svc.cluster.local
6. create ingress rules

NOTE: Demo code not to be running in production. Just wanted to give an idea of how it would work cross-namespaces

```yaml
---
#1
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: service-ns
---
#2
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: nginx
  name: nginx-internal
  namespace: service-ns
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "80"
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80  
  selector:
    app: nginx
---
#3
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: nginx
  name: nginx
  namespace: service-ns
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
        image: nginx
        name: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
      restartPolicy: Always
---
#4
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: ingress-ns
---
#5
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx
  namespace: ingress-ns
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: nginx-internal.service-ns.svc.cluster.local
  ports:
  - port: 80
---
#6
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: main-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  namespace: ingress-ns    
spec:
  rules:
    - host: whatever.domain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: nginx
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Answer (score 3):

Outside traffic comes through `ingress controller service` that is responsible for routing the traffic based on the defined routing rules or what we call `ingress rules` in k8s world.

In other words, `ingress` resources are just routing rules (think of it in away that's similar to DNS records) so when you define an `ingress` resource you just defined a rule for `ingress controller` to work on and route traffic based on such defined rules.

Solution:

1. Since `Ingress` are nothing but routing rules, you could define such rules anywhere in the cluster (in any `namespace`) and `controller` should pick them up as it monitors creation of such resources and react accordingly.

   Here's how to create ingress easily using `kubectl`

   Create an ingress

   `kubectl create ingress <name> -n namespaceName --rule="host/prefix=serviceName:portNumber"`

   **Note**: Add `--dry-run=client -oyaml` to generate `yaml` manifest file
2. Or you may create a service of type `ExternalName` in the same `namespace` where you have defined your `ingress`. such external service can point to any URL (a service that lives outside `namespace` or even k8s cluster)

   Here's an example:

   Create an `ExternalName` service

   `kubectl create service externalname ingress-ns -n namespaceName --external-name=serviceName.namespace.svc.cluster.local --tcp=80:80`

**Note**: Add `--dry-run=client -oyaml` to generate `yaml` manifest file

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx
  namespace: ingress-ns
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: serviceName.namespace.svc.cluster.local #or any external svc
  ports:
  - port: 80 #specify the port of service you want to expose 
    targetPort: 80 #port of external service
```

As described above, create an ingress as below:
`kubectl create ingress <name> -n namespaceName --rule="host/prefix=serviceName:portNumber"`

**Note**: Add `--dry-run=client -oyaml` to generate `yaml` manifest file

Answer (score 1):

ExternaNames service should be created without any **selector** options. So create the ExternaNames service in the namespace where your **ingress resource** is created and point the external name service to resolve the name of your application hosted in different namespace.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) For example you can add details and code snippet how can that be achieved. Take a look at the accepted answer as an example