# Ingress configuration for k8s in different namespaces

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I need to configure Ingress Nginx on azure k8s, and my question is if is possible to have ingress configured in one namespace et. ingress-nginx and some serivces in other namespace eg. resources?
My files looks like so:

```
# ingress-nginx.yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ingress-nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ingress-nginx
      annotations:
        prometheus.io/port: '10254'
        prometheus.io/scrape: 'true' 
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx-ingress-controller
          image: quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.12.0
          args:
            - /nginx-ingress-controller
            - --default-backend-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/default-http-backend
            - --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-configuration
            - --tcp-services-configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/tcp-services
            - --udp-services-configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/udp-services
            - --annotations-prefix=nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io
            - --publish-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx
          env:
            - name: POD_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: POD_NAMESPACE
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
          ports:
          - name: http
            containerPort: 80
          - name: https
            containerPort: 443
          livenessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 1
          readinessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: 10254
              scheme: HTTP
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 1
```

```
# configmap.yaml
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx-configuration
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app: ingress-nginx
---
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: tcp-services
  namespace: ingress-nginx
---
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: udp-services
  namespace: ingress-nginx
---
# default-backend.yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: default-http-backend
  labels:
    app: default-http-backend
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: default-http-backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: default-http-backend
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      containers:
      - name: default-http-backend
        # Any image is permissible as long as:
        # 1. It serves a 404 page at /
        # 2. It serves 200 on a /healthz endpoint
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/defaultbackend:1.4
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 8080
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 10m
            memory: 20Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 10m
            memory: 20Mi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: default-http-backend
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app: default-http-backend
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: default-http-backend
```

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app: ingress-nginx
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: ingress-nginx
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: http
  - name: https
    port: 443
    targetPort: https
```

```
        # app-ingress.yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app-ingress
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - api-sand.fake.com
  rules:
  - host: api-sand.fake.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: api-sand
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
```

And then I have some app running in the **resources namespace**, and problem is that I am getting the following error

```
error obtaining service endpoints: error getting service resources/api-sand from the cache: service resources/api-sand was not found
```

If I deploy api-sand in the same namespace where ingress is then this service works fine.

Comment: It's called a "fanout" ingress (see e.g. this GCP [example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes-engine-samples/blob/main/load-balancing/fanout-ingress.yaml))

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Instead of creating the ingress `app-ingress` in `ingress-nginx` namespace you should create it in the namespace where you have the service `api-sand`and the pod.

Alternatively there is way to achieve ingress in one namespace and service in another namespace via `externalName`.Checkout [Kubernetes Cross Namespace Ingress Network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51878195/kubernetes-cross-namespace-ingress-network/51899301#51899301)

Here is an example referred from [here](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/main/examples/ingress-resources/externalname-services).

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: test-service.namespacename.svc.cluster.local
```

---

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: my-service
          servicePort: 80
```

Comment: How did you get it working? I keep getting `service "default/my-service" is type "ExternalName", expected "NodePort" or "LoadBalancer";`

Comment: I couldn't get it to work either. I'm wondering if it's a provider and/or version issue? I'm on EKS 1.14...

Comment: (<error: endpoints "scc-worker-service" not found>) when describing the ingress, show this error. any clue to resolve?

Comment: if you read in the example link they speak only on ngnix plus

Comment: Is this specific to any ingress controllers? Seems this approach is not working for AWS ALB controller.

Comment: What about "Ingress configuration for k8s in different namespaces"? (I think this was the title)

Answer (score 191):

I would like to simplify the answer a bit for those who are relatively new to Kubernetes and its ingress options. There are 2 separate things that need to be present for ingress(es) to work:

1. **Ingress Controller**: a separate `DaemonSet` (a controller which runs on all nodes, including any future ones) along with a `Service` that can be used to utilize routing and proxying. It's based for example on NGINX which acts as the old-school reverse proxy receiving incoming traffic and forwarding it to HTTP(S) routes defined in the `Ingress` resources in point 2 below (distinguished by their different routes/URLs);
2. **Ingress rules**: separate Kubernetes resources with `kind: Ingress`. Will only take effect if Ingress Controller is already [deployed](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#prerequisites) on that node.

While **Ingress Controller can be deployed in any namespace** it is usually deployed in a namespace separate from your app services (e.g. `ingress` or `kube-system`). It can see `Ingress` rules in all other namespaces and pick them up. However, each of the **Ingress rules must reside in the namespace where the app that they configure reside.**

There are some workarounds for that, but this is the most common approach.

Comment: nice answer: Can I ask if when creating the Ingress rules, do they all need to be defined in a single Ingress rule, or can there be multiple Ingress rules within each namespace, each mapping to a service within that namespace? tx

Comment: Well, it's not as simple as with Network Policies. Not that NPs are simple, but there's a relatively straightforward way to merge them. With Ingress it can't be so simple because it's harder to standardize underlying Ingress Controller implementation, especially since those are built on top of completely independent components that existed long before Kubernetes inception, like Nginx. Having said that you are not the first one, @Choco, who entertain that thought: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/1539

Comment: So if I have 100 Microservices which should be accessible via 1 hostname (and separate paths) I have to put all those services in the same namespace so that they can use the same ingress resource??

Comment: It's such scenarios, you'd need to come up with a more advances networking architecture. Maybe it will be several levels of ingresses/proxies/gateway. Maybe ExternalName services. Is it a real or a hypothetical example?

Comment: hey @yuranos your answer looks great, and I do appreciate how you've addressed it to "those who are reletively new to Kubernetes" - but could you please expand on what you mean by "app" when you say "must reside in the namespace where the app that they configure reside" ?  There's no such thing called an "app", so does that mean the "service", the "deployment", or all of them?  thanks (from a relative newbie!)

Comment: Hey @AndyLorenz. Thanks. Yes, it means any workload resource(deployment, job, replicaset) that configures/controls your pods. They all reside in the same namespace.

Comment: Should I put the `LoadBalancer` service beside Ingress Controller, or beside `ingress`?

Comment: If you mean k8s service, then it's a separate level of abstraction, below your ingress. Ingress usually contains rules to point to k8s services.

Comment: +1 for the definitions. Also, I found this article helpful and an easy to understand example: https://vincentlauzon.com/2020/02/11/ingress-rules-in-different-kubernetes-namespaces

Answer (score 12):

It's possible actually, you can define ingress and a service with ExternalName type in namespace A, while the ExternalName points to DNS of the service in namespace B. For further details, please refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51899301/2995449

Answer (score 6):

Outside traffic comes through `ingress controller service` that is responsible for routing the traffic based on the defined routing rules or what we call `ingress rules` in k8s world.

In other words, `ingress` resources are just routing rules (think of it in away that's similar to DNS records) so when you define an `ingress` resource you just defined a rule for `ingress controller` to work on and route traffic based on such defined rules.

Solution:

1. Since `Ingress` are nothing but routing rules, you could define such rules anywhere in the cluster (in any `namespace`) and `controller` should pick them up as it monitors creation of such resources and react accordingly.

   Here's how to create ingress easily using `kubectl`

   `kubectl create ingress <name> -n namespaceName --rule="host/prefix=serviceName:portNumber"`

   **Note**: Add `--dry-run=client -oyaml` to generate `yaml` manifest file
2. Or you may create a service of type `ExternalName` in the same `namespace` where you have defined your `ingress`. such external service can point to any URL (a service that lives outside `namespace` or even k8s cluster)

   Here's an example that shows how to create an `ExternalName` service using kubectl:

   `kubectl create service externalname ingress-ns -n namespaceName --external-name=serviceName.namespace.svc.cluster.local --tcp=80:80 --dry-run=client -oyaml`

this should generate something similar to the following:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx
  namespace: ingress-ns
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: serviceName.namespace.svc.cluster.local #or any external svc
  ports:
  - port: 80 #specify the port of service you want to expose 
    targetPort: 80 #port of external service
```

As described above, create an ingress as below:
`kubectl create ingress <name> -n namespaceName --rule="host/prefix=serviceName:portNumber"`

**Note**: Add `--dry-run=client -oyaml` to generate `yaml` manifest file

Answer (score 1):

The way worked for me is creating ingress for each namespace

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  namespace: production
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
    - host: api.youtube.com
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: "/api/users"
            backend:
              service:
                name: youtube-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
```

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  namespace: development
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
    - host: dev.youtube.com
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: "/api/users"
            backend:
              service:
                name: youtube-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
```

Comment: If the ingress is a load balancer in cloud, you are spending a lot more by having a standalone LB for each NS

Answer (score -2):

There is a [way to configure](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) your default backend per ingress resource although the documentation says it is usually configured at the ingress controller level.

For example:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myingress
  namespace: myns
spec: 
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: default-http-backend
      port: 
        number: 80
...
```

Here default-http-backend must be defined in the same namespace as the ingress resource.