# Gke route based ingress for service running on different namespace

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

Infra - GKE
I have two version of service running on different namespace

```
 - web1 - namespaceA
 - web2 - namespaceB
```

Is it possible to have single gke ingress and use it to route traffic to both the services.

```
/web1 --- goes to web1 - namespaceA
/web2 -- goes to web2  - namespaceb
```

Comment: No. Kubernetes Ingress can only route to other services within the same namespace. You have to find a hacky way to do this. This type of use case goes against what "namespaces" are meant for in Kubernetes (isolation).

Answer (score 1):

### Solution A

This is for nginx-ingress

ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59845018/3854890

### Solution B

GKE Ingress in namespace A-> `Nginx` service in namespace A

with nginx.conf like:

```
    location /web1 {
        proxy_pass web1.namespaceA
    }
    
    location /web2 {
        proxy_pass web2.namespaceB
    }
```