# Kubernetes cert-manager with letsencrypt waiting on certificate issuance

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, lets-encrypt, cert-manager

I am trying to set up an Azure Kubernetes cluster with an HTTPS ingress controller for separate dev, staging, and prod environments. I have followed the Microsoft Azure guide on how to [Create an HTTPS ingress controller on Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-tls) which allows me to set up an HTTPS ingress controller for a single namespace, but my end goal is to have separate namespaces for the dev, staging, and prod environments. According to the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59844622/ingress-configuration-for-k8s-in-different-namespaces), the way to do this is to have the ingress controller on one namespace (`ingress` in my case), and then separate ingress rules for each namespace (`dev` in my case).

Hence I setup the nginx ingress controller and the cert-manager on the `ingress` namespace:

```
# Add the ingress-nginx repository
helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx

# Use Helm to deploy an NGINX ingress controller
helm install nginx-ingress ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx \
    --namespace ingress \
    --set controller.replicaCount=2 \
    --set controller.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
    --set defaultBackend.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
    --set controller.admissionWebhooks.patch.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux

# Label the ingress-basic namespace to disable resource validation
kubectl label namespace ingress cert-manager.io/disable-validation=true

# Add the Jetstack Helm repository
helm repo add jetstack https://charts.jetstack.io

# Update your local Helm chart repository cache
helm repo update

# Install the cert-manager Helm chart
helm install cert-manager jetstack/cert-manager \
  --namespace ingress \
  --version v0.16.1 \
  --set installCRDs=true \
  --set nodeSelector."kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
  --set webhook.nodeSelector."kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
  --set cainjector.nodeSelector."kubernetes\.io/os"=linux
```

I then create a `cluster-issuer.yml` file with the following:

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: email@address.com
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt
    solvers:
    - http01:
        ingress:
          class: nginx
          podTemplate:
            spec:
              nodeSelector:
                "kubernetes.io/os": linux
```

which I apply with

```
$ kubectl apply -f cluster-issuer.yml
```

Next I create an ingress rule on the `dev` namespace with the following `ingress.yml` file:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-dev
  namespace: dev
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt
    
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - domain.azure.com
    secretName: tls-secret-dev
  rules:
  - host: domain.azure.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: my-service
          servicePort: 80
        path: /dev/my-service(/|$)(.*)
```

and apply it:

```
$ kubectl apply -f ingress.yml
```

Now I check to see whether a secret has been created:

```
$ kubectl get certificate -n dev
NAME             READY   SECRET           AGE
tls-secret-dev   False   tls-secret-dev   61s
```

So it seems that something went wrong when creating the secret. If I look at the certificate, it seems that a certificate is requested, but it never gets further than that:

```
$ kubectl describe certificate tls-secret -n dev
Name:         tls-secret-dev
Namespace:    dev
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
API Version:  cert-manager.io/v1beta1
Kind:         Certificate
...
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:        2021-02-16T13:47:33Z
    Message:                     Issuing certificate as Secret does not exist
    Reason:                      DoesNotExist
    Status:                      False
    Type:                        Ready
    Last Transition Time:        2021-02-16T13:47:33Z
    Message:                     Issuing certificate as Secret does not exist
    Reason:                      DoesNotExist
    Status:                      True
    Type:                        Issuing
  Next Private Key Secret Name:  tls-secret-dev-6ngw8
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age   From          Message
  ----    ------     ----  ----          -------
  Normal  Issuing    70s   cert-manager  Issuing certificate as Secret does not exist
  Normal  Generated  70s   cert-manager  Stored new private key in temporary Secret resource "tls-secret-dev-6ngw8"
  Normal  Requested  70s   cert-manager  Created new CertificateRequest resource "tls-secret-dev-vtlbd"
```

Looking at the certificate request, an order is created:

```
$ kubectl describe certificaterequest tls-secret-dev-vtlbd -n dev
Name:         tls-secret-dev-vtlbd
Namespace:    dev
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  cert-manager.io/certificate-name: tls-secret-dev
              cert-manager.io/certificate-revision: 1
              cert-manager.io/private-key-secret-name: tls-secret-dev-6ngw8
API Version:  cert-manager.io/v1beta1
Kind:         CertificateRequest
...
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2021-02-16T13:47:33Z
    Message:               Waiting on certificate issuance from order dev/tls-secret-dev-vtlbd-526778456: ""
    Reason:                Pending
    Status:                False
    Type:                  Ready
Events:
  Type    Reason        Age   From          Message
  ----    ------        ----  ----          -------
  Normal  OrderCreated  3m3s  cert-manager  Created Order resource dev/tls-secret-dev-vtlbd-526778456
```

Inspecting the order is where the trail seems to run cold:

```
$ kubectl describe order tls-secret-dev-vtlbd-526778456 -n dev
Name:         tls-secret-dev-vtlbd-526778456
Namespace:    dev
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  cert-manager.io/certificate-name: tls-secret-dev
              cert-manager.io/certificate-revision: 1
              cert-manager.io/private-key-secret-name: tls-secret-dev-6ngw8
API Version:  acme.cert-manager.io/v1beta1
Kind:         Order
...
Status:
Events:  <none>
```

**Question:** How do I get the certificate manager to stop waiting on certificate issuance so I can finish setting up my HTTPS ingress controller?

Comment: Hello, have you configured your `DNS` (record `A`) with your domain so that it is pointing to the Service of type `LoadBalancer` of your `nginx-ingress` controller? Also your `domain` (`domain.azure.com`) in `Ingress` and `email address` (`email@address.com`) in `ClusterIssuer` are placeholders values and not your actual values by any chance?

Comment: @DawidKruk The domain name and email address are placeholders, yes. I have not configured a record A, but instead configured a FQDN as described in the linked guide, based on the external IP given by the ingress controller.

Comment: Following on this topic, your `domain.azure.com` DNS resolution points directly at the `Ingress` controller, right? If not please try to add this `A` record and tell if you've managed to generate this certificate.