# ingress for same applications in different namespace

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

I have an application that has 5 micro services lets say, nginx,mysql,phpmyadmin,backend-1 and backend-2.

I'm to deploy this application in six different namespace lets say project-1, project-2, project-3, project-4 and project-5.

i would like to config one DNS host "app.dummy.com" to access these application in a way-

```
app.dummy.com/project-1/nginx
app.dummy.com/project-1/phpmyadmin
app.dummy.com/project-2/nginx
app.dummy.com/project-2/phpmyadmin
app.dummy.com/project-3/nginx
app.dummy.com/project-3/phpmyadmin
app.dummy.com/project-4/nginx
app.dummy.com/project-4/phpmyadmin
app.dummy.com/project-5/nginx
app.dummy.com/project-5/phpmyadmin
```

how should is config ingress for nginx,phpmyadmin each namespace? becaz the service name for these service remains same across all the namespace.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ingress configuration for k8s in different namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59844622/ingress-configuration-for-k8s-in-different-namespaces)

Comment: no. it is talking explaining my queries.

Comment: In kubernetes we normally solve this with a mix of DNS along with either ingress or service mesh