# Can Knative's Kafka Broker be fed with events from outside its cluster?

Tags: knative, knative-serving, knative-eventing

When I setup a kafka broker, its URL by default using

e.g. "http://kafka-broker-ingress.knative-eventing.svc.cluster.local/example/default"

I am only able to send event from resource within k8 cluster.

Is it possible to setup a kafka broker using public facing URL, so that it could receive events from outside the cluster? If can. How?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't supported out-of-the-box but you can use a [Kubernetes ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/).

A minimal example:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-default-broker
  namespace: knative-eventing
spec:
  rules:
  - host: <my_host>
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /example/default
        pathType: Exact
        backend:
          service:
            name: kafka-broker-ingress
            port:
              number: 80
```

If you want to create the ingress resource in your `example` namespace and connect it to the `kafka-broker-ingress` service, look at [Kubernetes Cross Namespace Ingress Network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51878195/kubernetes-cross-namespace-ingress-network/51899301).