# validate ingress-hostnames in a shared kubernetes cluster (provisioned by rancher) based on a namespace-specific annotation or similar

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

I'm searching for a possibility to validate hostnames from ingress-ressources with different specs for different namespaces.

## Scenario:

- Rancher 2.7.5
- k8s-version RKE2 v1.26.6
- on downstream vSphere-Cluster (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS)
- nginx-ingress-controller with default wildcard-certificate for *.cl01.k8s.domain.tld

## Idea:

We have set up a "shared" k8s-cluster via Rancher to provide easy-to-use k8s-resources for our DEVs.

They'll get a Rancher project and can use more than one namespace.

The Rancher-PRoject and needed Namespaces will be provided externally via selfService tool only to be sure having the needed naming convention etc.

Each Rancher-project has a unique (randomized) name, f.eg "k12345", so every namespace in a Rancher project get a prefix with the Rancher-project-name, f.eg "k12345-default"

## Challenge:

Because of the shared usage we need to validate the Ingress-hostnames per namespace. We don't want to use a separate ingress-controller for each project.

We want to use the default wildcard-certificate for all ingress-resources which are using the ingress-controller. We don't want to set up a subdomain for each project.

The Hostname should be created like something-.cl01.k8s.domain.tld (example: something-k12345.cl01.k8s.domain.tld)

We're able to set up annotations in all created namespaces to have the needed information in each namespace.

I have tried different ways but didn't find a working way. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to run multiple Ingress NGINX Controllers in a Kubernetes cluster?

Comment: If yes,it is doable and you can point to namesspace.

Comment: No, only one Ingress-Controller for all users. But the users are able to set up Ingress-resources.

Comment: Then this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51878195/kubernetes-cross-namespace-ingress-network/51899301#51899301 can maybe help.

Comment: Thanks, but that is another scenario... In my environment any user is able to create Ingress-resources and point them to the ingress-controller. This is working fine.

But to be sure that all users are using the right hostname-suffix I need some validation magic. ;)